# Why does this C code take so long to compile and execute if the variable is not initialized?

Tags: c, for-loop, variable-initialization

The following C code takes so long to compile and execute.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int max;
    printf("Enter a value for max: ");
    scanf("%d", &max);

    for (int i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But, If I initialize the max variable with some number like

```
int max = 0;
```

The Compilation and execution is almost instantaneous. Can someone explain why?

Edit:

When I printed the value of the variable max before my input, it showed 2203648 (some garbage value). Instead of "int max = 0", if i assign

```
int max = 2203648;
```

the compilation and execution takes the same long time. But, as mentioned earlier, if i assign max say

```
int max = 200;
```

the compilation and execution is instantaneous. Does it have to do anything with the pre-assigned garbage value?

Also, this problem occurs only in windows computers, I tested with ubuntu, and the compilation and execution is instantaneous in both version of the code.

In Windows 10:

compilation and execution, as of "Enter a value for max: " appears on screen:

without variable initialization = around 8 seconds

with variable initialization = instantaneous

compiler - gcc

Comment: So what is the difference in time?

Comment: With what compiler? Executing how? How long is "so long"?

Comment: The compiler is gcc. Without variable initialization, the compilation takes around 8 seconds. With vairable initialization, its almost instantaneous.

Comment: @SuryaNarayanan: This sounds very strange. Can you reliably reproduce the problem? Or could it be coincidence? Do you have maybe other programs running that cause frequent slowdowns of your computer? Can you reproduce the problem on more than one computer?

Comment: I would guess that you have a pre-compiled binary for one version or the other sitting in your project folder. And then your IDE notices that one version does not contain any changes compared to the one that generated said binary. Are you using any IDE and if so which one?

Comment: I used VS Code.

Comment: You say "compilation and execution" is affected, but you only report compilation time. Is also execution affected?

Comment: I have tested several times and I was able to reliably able to reproduce in several Windown PCs.

Comment: Yes execution also takes some considerable time before "Enter the value for max: " shows up on screen.

Comment: Run the compile command manually, remember to clean between each run. I believe the time should be almost be the same. However when running the compiled binary then the antivirus blocks one of your exe file so it starts much more slowly. I've experienced that myself a lot

Comment: Is the code that you posted an **exact copy** of the actual code you are using? Or did you maybe make a slight modification (which you consider insignificant) before posting it, without actually testing the modified code?

Comment: @Andreaswenzel This is the exact copy without any modifications. Also, what I wonder is, why this problem doesn't occur in Ubuntu. It only occurs in Windows computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scanf` is failing. Check the return value.

i.e.

```
   if (scanf("%d", &max) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read max");
      exit(1);
   }
```

`max` is probably some large value hence the large amount of time

**EDIT**

The delay to see the prompt is that the `printf` is in a buffer and will not be displayed until the loop completes

Comment: As you have said, max is pre-assigned a very huge garbage value.  Is that the reason why the compilation and execution might have taken so long?

Comment: Most likely I guess. Simply print it out before the loop

Comment: But you _can't_ print or otherwise read an uninitialised variable, as that always yields UB, and UB can include the mere act of adding a print to make the value _seem_ like zero. Basically, one must simply avoid UB, instead of trying to reason about it.

Comment: @underscode_d In C you can print an uninitialized variable. It is not UB the print. Its value is some random value. It still has a value.

Comment: This answer would explain a delay of 8 seconds after the prompt `"Enter a value for max:"` appears. However, OP stated that the delay is 8 seconds before the prompt appears. Therefore, this answer does not answer OP's question (assuming that the information provided by OP is accurate).

Comment: See edit for an explanation of that

Comment: @EdHeal: I highly doubt that this is the reason for the behavior described by OP. However, you are right that it is possible, as [§7.21.3 ¶3 of the ISO C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p3) only recommends (not does not require) that `stdout` is flushed when input is requested from `stdin`. This could easily be tested by OP, by inserting an `fflush(stdout);` statement before the `scanf` statement.

Answer (score -1):

I think variable initialization of max=0 doesn't make that great deal of a difference, but god knows why in ypur case its taking 8seconds. I think you should reinstall your GCC Compiler set your path variables correctly once more, and try the above code on a different IDE.